# Visual Studio 2005 Intellisense with Rhino Mocks

Tags: intellisense, rhino-mocks

The Rhino Mocks download comes with a "Rhino.Mocks.xml" file that apparently adds Intellisense for Rhino Mocks.

What do you need to do with this file in order to get it to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put it in the same directory as the DLL you're referencing, and it should be picked up automatically.

Comment: OK - got some of it to work but when I type "Expect.Call(xxx)).IgnoreArguments();", there is no Intellisense for the IgnoreArguments / Return etc. ?

Comment: Perhaps that documentation hasn't been written. I suggest you download the source and check - or look in the XML file.